# Построение графика в виджете

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt6, pyqtgraph, qtableview

Необходимо реализовать функцию, которая при нажатии кнопки "Подгрузить данные", данные из ***Excel*** подтягивались и визуализировались в виде графика в виджет - "`widgetGraph`", и в виде таблицы в QTableView - "`tableView`".

```
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(815, 403)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.widgetGraph = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widgetGraph.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 50, 311, 231))
        self.widgetGraph.setObjectName("widgetGraph")
        self.tableView = QtWidgets.QTableView(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(410, 50, 331, 231))
        self.tableView.setObjectName("tableView")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 10, 311, 31))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.textEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(410, 10, 331, 31))
        self.textEdit_2.setObjectName("textEdit_2")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(34, 290, 301, 24))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 815, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.textEdit.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><meta charset=\"utf-8\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"hr { height: 1px; border-width: 0; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'Segoe UI\'; font-size:9pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-weight:700;\">График</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.textEdit_2.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><meta charset=\"utf-8\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"hr { height: 1px; border-width: 0; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'Segoe UI\'; font-size:9pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-weight:700;\">Табличные значения</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Подгрузить данные"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обратите внимание, я заменил

```
self.widgetGraph = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
```

на

```
self.widgetGraph = pg.PlotWidget(title='PlotItem')
```

Одно из возможных решений может выглядеть примерно так:

```
#from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets                     # PyQt6

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets                      # PyQt5

import pandas as pd                                             # +++
import pyqtgraph as pg                                          # +++


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(815, 403)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        
#        self.widgetGraph = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widgetGraph = pg.PlotWidget(title='PlotItem')               # !!! +++
        
        self.widgetGraph.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 50, 311, 231))
        self.widgetGraph.setObjectName("widgetGraph")
        
        self.tableView = QtWidgets.QTableView(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(410, 50, 331, 231))
        self.tableView.setObjectName("tableView")
        
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 10, 311, 31))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        
        self.textEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(410, 10, 331, 31))
        self.textEdit_2.setObjectName("textEdit_2")
        
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(34, 290, 301, 24))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 815, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
#        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
#        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
#        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.textEdit.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><meta charset=\"utf-8\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"hr { height: 1px; border-width: 0; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'Segoe UI\'; font-size:9pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-weight:700;\">График</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.textEdit_2.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><meta charset=\"utf-8\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"hr { height: 1px; border-width: 0; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'Segoe UI\'; font-size:9pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-weight:700;\">Табличные значения</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Подгрузить данные"))


class DataFrameModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    DtypeRole = QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1000
    ValueRole = QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1001

    def __init__(self, df=pd.DataFrame(), parent=None):
        super(DataFrameModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self._dataframe = df

    def setDataFrame(self, dataframe):
        self.beginResetModel()
        self._dataframe = dataframe.copy()
        self.endResetModel()

    def dataFrame(self):
        return self._dataframe

    dataFrame = QtCore.pyqtProperty(pd.DataFrame, fget=dataFrame, fset=setDataFrame)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int, QtCore.Qt.Orientation, result=str)
    def headerData(self, section: int, orientation: QtCore.Qt.Orientation, role: int = QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
                return self._dataframe.columns[section]
            else:
                return str(self._dataframe.index[section])
        return QtCore.QVariant()

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        if parent.isValid():
            return 0
        return len(self._dataframe.index)

    def columnCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        if parent.isValid():
            return 0
        return self._dataframe.columns.size

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if not index.isValid() or not (0 <= index.row() < self.rowCount() \
            and 0 <= index.column() < self.columnCount()):
            return QtCore.QVariant()
        row = self._dataframe.index[index.row()]
        col = self._dataframe.columns[index.column()]
        dt = self._dataframe[col].dtype

        val = self._dataframe.iloc[row][col]
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return str(val)
        elif role == DataFrameModel.ValueRole:
            return val
        if role == DataFrameModel.DtypeRole:
            return dt
        return QtCore.QVariant()

    def roleNames(self):
        roles = {
            QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole: b'display',
            DataFrameModel.DtypeRole: b'dtype',
            DataFrameModel.ValueRole: b'value'
        }
        return roles


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.textEdit.setReadOnly(True)
        self.textEdit.setMaximumHeight(30)
        self.textEdit_2.setReadOnly(True)
        self.textEdit_2.setMaximumHeight(30)
                
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Построить график')         # +++
        
        self.spinboxX = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(prefix="X : ", suffix=" столбец.") # +++
        self.spinboxX.setRange(0, 1)
        self.spinboxY = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(prefix="Y : ", suffix=" столбец.") # +++
        self.spinboxY.setRange(0, 1)
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        layoutH = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.widget)
        layoutH.addWidget(self.spinboxX)
        layoutH.addWidget(self.spinboxY)
        self.widget.hide()
        
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.textEdit, 0, 0, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.textEdit_2, 0, 1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.widgetGraph, 1, 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tableView, 1, 1)        
        self.layout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2, 2, 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 2, 1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.widget, 3, 1) 
        
        self.layout.setColumnStretch(0, 1)
        self.layout.setColumnStretch(1, 1)
        
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.load_data)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.draw_graph)
        
    def draw_graph(self):
        if self.tableView.model() is None:
            return
        header_col = self.spinboxX.value()    
        header = self.tableView.model().headerData(header_col, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        x = self.tableView.model()._dataframe[header].values.tolist() 

        header_col = self.spinboxY.value()    
        header = self.tableView.model().headerData(header_col, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        y = self.tableView.model()._dataframe[header].values.tolist() 

        self.pg_calc(x, y)        

    def pg_calc(self, x, y):
        self.widgetGraph.clear()
        self.widgetGraph.plot(x, y, pen='r')        

    def load_data(self):
        self.file_open()

    def file_open(self):
        path, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            self, 
            'Open Excel', 
            '', 
            '*.xlsx *.xls'
        )
        if path:                                          
            df = pd.read_excel(path)
            model = DataFrameModel(df)
            self.tableView.setModel(model)

            columns = self.tableView.model().columnCount()
            self.spinboxX.setRange(0, columns-1)
            self.spinboxY.setRange(0, columns-1)
            self.spinboxY.setValue(1)
            self.widget.show()
   

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @AndrewGans я подправил свой пример. Скопируйте его полностью и поменяйте импорт.

Comment: подскажите, а как на Qt6 будет выглядеть данный код? Если поменять 5 на 6 в верхних строчках, то появляется ошибка: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt6.Qt'"

Comment: @AndrewGans я же убрал строку, в которой у вас возникала ошибка. Скопируйте код полностью еще раз и поменяйте импорт  5 на 6. Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: да, я так и сделал. Сейчас другая ошибка:
AttributeError: type object 'Qt' has no attribute 'UserRole'

Comment: @AndrewGans sorry, у меня нет PyQt6. Попробуйте заменить в строках, которые содержат  `QtCore.Qt.UserRole` на `QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.UserRole`

Comment: @AndrewGans если мои ответы учат вас чему-то новому - не стесняйтесь отмечать их и как полезные.

Comment: подскажите, а где в коде можно поменять фон графика и добавить подписи осей?

Comment: @AndrewGans  Welcome to the documentation for pyqtgraph https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: @AndrewGans если у вас есть другие проблемы - задайте новый вопрос.